# How do I create an email trigger/workflow from SP list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, metadata, sharepoint-email

I need to have an email sent to users based upon not completing an action in a sharePoint list. For instance if a task status was blank or incomplete, it would notify the user to provide the update. this could be based on due date approaching or missed (due date is a column within list), to remind the user to provide an update within the status column. Is this possible with some style of workflow?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to run the Pause Until action and set the date you'd like to send the email.

You might want to create a workflow parameter and calculate, for example, due date minus 2 days.

I'm assuming by the way you have worded the question that you are comfortable creating the email actions within designer through custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

Pause until action would make the workflow sleep and in case the date is changed it will not take updated date but wait for original date to come.

Another solution could be - you can navigate to list settings --> "Information Management Policy Settings" --> Item / or custom content type that you are using --> Check "Enable Retention" --> Add retention stage --> Delete the due date and number of days before which the reminder mail should be sent -->  Action : Select start workflow --> Select the workflow

This could be the solution for the requirement.